# explicit destructor

Tags: c++, destructor

The following code is just used to illustrate my question.

```
template<class T>
class array<T>
{
 public:
    // constructor
    array(cap = 10):capacity(cap)
    {element = new T [capacity]; size =0;}

    // destructor
    ~array(){delete [] element;}
    void erase(int i);
    private:
      T *element;
      int capacity;
      int size;
};



template<class T>
void class array<T>::erase(int i){
     // copy
     // destruct object
    element[i].~T();  ////
    // other codes
}
```

If I have `array<string> arr` in main.cpp. When I use `erase(5)`, the object of `element[5]` is destroyed but the space of `element[5]` will not be deallocated, can I just use `element[5] = "abc"` to put a new value here? or should I have to use placement new to put new value in the space of `element [5]`?

When program ends, the `arr<string>` will call its own destructor which also calls `delete [] element`. So the destructor of string will run to destroy the object first and then free the space. But since I have explicitly destruct the `element[5]`, does that matter the destructor (which is called by the arr's destuctor) run twice to destruct `element[5]`? I know the space can not be deallocated twice, how about the object?  I made some tests and found it seems fine if I just destruct object twice instead of deallocating space twice.

***Update***

The answers are：

`(1)I have to use placement new if I explicitly call destructor.`

`(2) repeatedly destructing object is defined as undefined behavior which may be accepted in most systems but should try to avoid this practice.`

Comment: This is a bad approach. Calling a destructor twice as undefined behavior, of which "seems fine" is a completely acceptable result. It's not fine, though. Though "erasing" from an array makes little sense to me anyway.

Comment: I agree with @GMan:  what does it mean to "erase" elements from an array?  Are you trying to emulate the C++ `std::vector` implementation?  If so, are you moving all the elements after the erased element down to "fill the hole"?

Comment: @ Gman: "erase" makes little sense to me too.

Comment: @James: Yes, I try but the method above is not in the right direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the placement-new syntax:

```
new (element + 5) string("abc");
```

It would be incorrect to say `element[5] = "abc"`; this would invoke `operator=` on `element[5]`, which is not a valid object, yielding undefined behavior.

> When program ends, the `arr<string>` will call its own destructor which also calls `delete [] element`.

This is wrong:  you are going to end up calling the destructor for objects whose destructors have already been called (e.g., `elements[5]` in the aforementioned example).  This also yields undefined behavior.

Consider using the `std::allocator` and its interface.  It allows you easily to separate allocation from construction.  It is used by the C++ Standard Library containers.

Comment: The standard allows the destructor to be called explicitly, as long as placement new is used to put an object of identical type back into that location before the automatic destructor call is made.

Comment: @Ben:  Right, but it doesn't look like new elements are being constructed in place.  It's hard to say since the OP has only posted a small snippet, but I would not assume that an `erase` function would also create new objects.  Regardless, using the `allocator` is the way to go here:  it makes all of this quite straightforward (well, as straightforward as this sort of thing gets, at least...)

Comment: Yes, but the OP did ask about placement new.  So the answer is that not only is placement new allowed in this scenario, it is *required*.

Comment: @Ben:  Oh; I see what you meant.

Answer (score 3):

Just to explain further exactly how the UD is likely to bite you....

If you `erase()` an element - explicitly invoking the destructor - that destructor may do things like decrement reference counters + cleanup, delete pointers etc..  When your array<> destructor then does a `delete[] element`, that will invoke the destructors on each element in turn, and for erased elements those destructors are likely to repeat their reference count maintenance, pointer deletion etc., but this time the initial state isn't as they expect and their actions are likely to crash the program.

For that reason, as Ben says in his comment on James' answer, you absolutely must have replaced an erased element - using placement new - before the array's destructor is invoked, so the destructor will have some legitimate state from which to destruct.

The simplest type of `T` that illustrates this problem is:

```
struct T
{
    T() : p_(new int) { }
    ~T() { delete p_; }
    int* p_;
};
```

Here, the `p_` value set by `new` would be deleted during an `erase()`, and if unchanged when `~array()` runs.  To fix this, `p_` must be changed to something for which `delete` is valid before `~array()` - either by somehow clearing it to 0 or to another pointer returned by `new`.  The most sensible way to do that is by the placement `new`, which will construct a new object, obtaining a new and valid value for `p_`, overwriting the old and useless memory content.

That said, you might think you could construct types for which repeated destructor was safe: for example, by setting `p_` to 0 after the `delete`.  That would probably work on most systems, but I'm pretty sure there's something in the Standard saying to invoke the destructor twice is UD regardless.